# Can anyone help pinpoint why I get this Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined error for google maps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am trying to render the google map api on my web page but I keep getting this error:

```
edit:1076 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here is the process. The call that leads to the rendering of the api map begins in an `edit.html.haml` file.

`edit.html.haml`

```
........html.....
........html.....
........html.....
.col-md-5.col-md-push-1
  .form-group
    %label.control-label!= t('.city_and_country')
      .controls
        %p.enabled
          %input.form-control#location_scratch{ type: :text, autocomplete: :off, value: @account.location }
              %a{ href: 'javascript:EditMap.clearLocation();' }= t('clear')
          %p.error#not_found{ style: 'display:none' }
            = t('.location_error_message')
              #map

              #-----THIS IS WHERE IT STARTS-------------
              != map_init('map,' @account.latitude ? 7 : 0)
              #-------------------------------------------

              = f.hidden_field :location
              = f.hidden_field :country_code
              = f.hidden_field :latitude
              = f.hidden_field :longitude
```

From `map_init` in the `edit.html.haml` file we then travel to the `map_helper.rb` file

```
map_helper.rb

module MapHelper
  def map_init(id, zoom = 2)
    map_script_load + map_js_initialization(id, zoom)
  end

  private

  def map_script_load
    key = Rails.application.config.google_maps_api_key
    uri = "#{request.ssl? ? 'https' : 'http'}://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=#{key}"
    "<script async defer src='#{uri}' type='text/javascript'></script>"
  end

  def map_js_initialization(id, zoom)
    javascript_tag <<-JSCRIPT
     $(document).on('page:change', function() {
        Map.load('#{id}', 25, 12, 2);
        Map.moveTo(25, 12, #{zoom});
      });
    JSCRIPT
  end
```

and then from there it goes to a `Map.js` file that calls the `load` and `moveTo` methods.

The problem though is in the `map_js_initialization` method. The `JSCRIPT` javascript code fails for `$(document).on('page:change')` Why is it failing for the jQuery object? I saw that an error like this occurs because the google maps api loads before the jquery source code. However, I've also placed an `async defer` on the maps and still no change in result.

I have `require jquery` in my `application.js` file and then in my `application.html.haml` file I have

```
!!!5
%html
  %head
    - page_title = content_for?(:html_title) ? "#{yield(:html_title)}" : t('.openhub')
    %title= page_title
    %meta{ name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' }
    %meta{ name: 'description', content: page_context[:description] }
    %meta{ name: 'keywords', content: page_context[:keywords] }
    %meta{ name: 'digits-consumer-key', content: ENV['DIGITS_CONSUMER_KEY'] }
    %meta{ name: 'google-site-verification', content: 'jKkWeVQ0tB1bffJYg7xXAtcIM-nrjjVxhP3ohb8UH2A' }
    = yield :custom_head
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body{ zoom: 1 }
    = yield :session_projects_banner
    .container#page
      %header= render partial: 'layouts/partials/header'
      = render partial: 'layouts/partials/page'
      .clear
      %footer= render partial: 'layouts/partials/footer'

    = yield(:javascript) if content_for?(:javascript)
    = javascript_include_tag 'application',
                         'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js',
                         'https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js',
                         '//cdn.optimizely.com/js/3568250046.js',
                         cache: 'cached_js_files',
                         async: true


 - if Rails.env.production?
      <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
      var hm = document.createElement('script'); hm.type ='text/javascript'; hm.async = true;
      hm.src = ('++u-heatmap-it+log-js').replace(/[+]/g,'/').replace(/-/g,'.');
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
      })();
      </script>
```

So in conclusion. I should be able to render the maps because I have at the top of my `<head>` tag `application.js` which has `jquery` and then the call to the api comes afterwards. Am I missing something here?

Comment: According to your code, you have `javascript_include_tag` as a very last thing in your layout, not in your head tag.

Comment: Yeah it looks like I didn't look carefully, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nifty property to solve the problem that I was having. While the problem that jquery was not loading in the correct order, the map still was not rendering for some reason. This little snippet of code solved my problem.

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
       Map.load('#{id}', 25, 12, 2);
       Map.moveTo(25, 12, #{zoom});
     }
   };
```